# Error when assigning a value to a string variable

Tags: c#, .net

This is the text:

```
<img src="http://rotter.net/forum/Images/locked_icon_general.gif" border=
```

And what i want to do is:

```
string firstTag = "<img src="http://rotter.net/forum/Images/locked_icon_general.gif" border=";
```

So if I use a breakpoint and look at it I will see:

```
<img src="http://rotter.net/forum/Images/locked_icon_general.gif" border=
```

I want top assign the text the line:

But im getting errors:

```
string firstTag = <img src="http://rotter.net/forum/Images/locked_icon_general.gif" border=";

Error   6   The type or namespace name 'img' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   7   The type or namespace name 'border' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I want to assign this:

But since there are many """" in the

Comment: ok thats great, but its hard to tell what you exactly need to do.

Comment: Please try to describe your problem a bit more in detail. Almost impossible to give you an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a basic syntax problem. You should read a C# Guide; however, for this particular problem the issue is the quotations. You need to escape them.
Here is what I believe you want.

```
string firstTag = "<img src=\"http://rotter.net/forum/Images/locked_icon_general.gif\" border=\"";
```

You may also do this:

```
string firstTag = @"<img src=""http://rotter.net/forum/Images/locked_icon_general.gif"" border=""";
```

You can read up more on this here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx